# Qt access TextEdit's text in other scope

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I'm trying to create a simple IDE. At the moment I'm totally failing! I have some actions and when I click on the action "new" it should add a new page to my TabWidget and create a TextEdit inside. This actually works but I do not know how to use the TextEdit. For example if I want to save it, I need access to the text of the textEdit but how?

Code:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionNew_triggered()
{
    QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit();
    ui->Tabs->addTab(textEdit, "New Tab");
    ui->Tabs->setCurrentIndex( ui->Tabs->count() );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some variable that is out of the scope to be able to access it.

Your `textEdit` is defined in local scope of the function. If you want to access to for example on global space of the cpp file you could define it as

```
static QTextEdit *textEdit;
```

outside of any function.

A better idea may be to define it as member variable of the `MainWindow` class:

```
private:
    QTextEdit *m_textEdit;
```

Remember that memory allocated with `new` is allocated until you `delete` it.

Comment: yeah well I did define a variable in my class but somehow i couldnt access it... did you try it?

Comment: If you defined it in the `MainWindow` class, you should be able to access it within any member function of it (here `MainWindow::on_actionNew_triggered`). What error do you get?